# I want to increase blogger number of posts displayed?

Tags: blogger

when i go next page then show max 8 post i want it show 28 post . but i can not do it. i already try to replace this code

```
 

    data:label.url
```

to this code

```
    data:label.url + "?max-results=28"
```

but it's not working.it's show like this http://www.dewdropzone.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2012-10-25T08%3A19%3A00%2B06%3A00&max-results=8
i also try to change from blogger setting but it's also not working. anyone can tell me how i can do it?

[my site](http://www.dewdropzone.blogspot.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you must find this codes in Edit HTML :

```
var pageCount=8;
```

Change with this :

```
var pageCount=28;
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not working for me. I feel frustrated.

Answer (score 2):

Well since you are using blogger/blogspot you can simply go to `settings--> posts/comments` and edit the number at `Show at most`